# Is this the case of the wrong aircraft shown on airline website?

Tags: seating, aircraft

I see multiple source publishing that EgyptAir will be servicing the Toronto to Cairo route through a new set of 787 Dreamliners. See sources:

- https://thepointsguy.com/news/egyptair-787-new-business-class/
- https://www.routesonline.com/news/38/airlineroute/282419/egyptair-schedules-787-9-toronto-service-in-oct-2019/
- and many others...

However, on the EgyptAir website itself, this isn't the case. As an example, see flight for end of October showing the old Boeing 777. This is also the case for dates in to the following months.

[image: EgyptAir Timetable]

Could it be that the EgyptAir website itself isn't up to date? Are there are places to find accurate servicing aircraft?

Comment: Of course it's possible that the EgyptAir website isn't correct, and that the company will use the 787 on that route. It's also possible that the company said they'd use the 787 on that route (hence the news releases), then changed their minds. Only EgyptAir knows for sure. Have you called and asked them?

Comment: This flight appears to be operated on 777s as of now: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ms996

Comment: And Google Flights (https://www.google.com/flights#flt=YYZ.CAI.2019-11-14;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o) shows the 787 to be used on the Toronto > LHR segment on a random date in November 2019. So I'd say it's _likely_ to be a 787 on this segment.

Comment: Also you can't rely on this information anyways, airlines can and do change equipment as they see fit, there's no guarantee whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Airlines update their master schedules on cycles, usually with seasons.

Each update will have the flights "frequency" which shows the days of the week in which the flight will operate, the effective date of the frequency, new routes and so on. Something like:

```
XX#### YZZ 0300 CAI 2000 B773 MT.RF.U EFF 10OCT19
```

So the flights you see are based on the last master schedule version, which had the B777-300. Once Egyptair releases their updated schedule it will be updated everywhere with the new data, including the aircraft type or any other updates in the flight information.

Comment: Where can one find this data? Is this a sandman ex cabin crew trick? :P

Comment: @JoErNanO i have no idea where to find it, pizza man

Comment: Ah so the one you posted is a made up example? That's unfortunate this would have been a great tool for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no guarantee that you will be flying on the plane shown on the airline website since airlines tend to change equipment depending on their needs. However, as you correctly found out, [Egypt Air is in the process of updating their equipment to 787 Dreamliners](https://thepointsguy.com/news/egyptair-787-new-business-class/), so it is safe to say that, at some point in the future, the Toronto to Cairo route will be serviced by 787.[As of now, the flight seems to be operated by a 777.](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ms996) [Google Flights also shows a 777 for the same segment in November](https://www.google.com/flights#flt=YYZ.CAI.2019-11-14;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o).
Predicting when the switch will happen is a completely different story.

Comment: Your Google Flights link for November 14th shows a 777, not a 787.

Comment: @jcaron true. So do flights in December.